# Best IDE for HTML5, Javascript, CSS, Jquery support with GUI building tools

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html, canvas

I am doing a project using the RGraph HTML5 canvas package to draw graphs. I need to build a good looking GUI aswell. I have been playing around with Netbeans and it doesn't really have much to offer unless i'm missing some plugins. Is there any other IDE to fit my needs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: <shaking head>I have a strong feeling that Aptana is going to be the unanimous choice. That is until we get to Mac only stuff :)</shaking head>

Comment: "Best" is a subjective question. There is no definitive answer for this. Moreover, you did not include crucial information (like the OS you are developing on). Unfortunately, this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just as an FYI - "best" questions aren't the norm at SO, but I will give you a list of options, just as a service.

OK then. These two are the ones I used:

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)

[Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.org/products/studio3)

and then there is always [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/).

**UPDATE 20 March 2013 **

Well, **[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)** is the one to heavily consider. Heavily.

Comment: +1 for the "Heavily" part.

Comment: I second sublime 2. nice call batman :) But I think the OP was more after a sort of dreamweaver hybrid... Sorry man, you're either a coder or a designer :D

Answer (score 12):

## Update for 2024

Definitely in 2024 lighter editors with plugins seem the way to go. I just use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (Mac/Windows) with plugins. The atom folks have started [Zed](https://zed.dev/), which might be a nice alternative. The JetBrains folks have started [Fleet](https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/), which is currently free during this preview period.

## Update for 2016

A lot of great editors have come out since my original answer. I currently use the following text editors: [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (Mac/Windows), [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (Mac/Windows) and [Atom](https://atom.io/) (Mac/Windows). I also use the following IDEs: [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/) (Windows/Paid & Free Versions) and [Jetrbrains WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (Windows/Paid, tried the demo and liked it).

My preference is using [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

## Original Answer

[Microsoft Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) and [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) are great.

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) and [Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) are also great but may be overkill for you.

For just plain text editors, [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is really cool

Comment: +1 for the hint about Microsoft Web Matrix. Thanks!

Comment: WebMatrix have no wysiwyg support.

Comment: @a.boussema Sorry, I don't get your point.

Comment: wysiwyg : What You See Is What You Get, editors makes it possible to see  your pages at the same time as you edit these, without having to Run the website. Helpful when applying design and CSS. for further info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG   Or google for it

Comment: Yeah, but there are a ton of great IDE/text editors that aren't WYSIWYG.  That doesn't make them bad.  I personally haven't used WYSIWYG in years for HTML development.

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience to build website with html, css en javascript is just to stick with plain text editors with ftp support. I am using Espresso or/and Coda on my mac. But Textmate with Cyberduck(ftp client) is also a great combination, imo. For developing in Windows I recommend notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal experience Adobe edge is the best tool for HTML5. It's still in preview mode but you will download it free from Adobe site.

Comment: Note: As of November 2015, Edge Animate is no longer being actively developed.