# Error with flip toogle switch in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I need to made a calculator for an app with Jquery Mobile, but it doesn´t work whit the flip toogle switch, this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosis() {
    $peso = $('#peso').get(0).value
    $dosis = $('#dosis').get(0).value
    $concentracion = $('#concentracion').get(0).value

    if ($peso=='' || $dosis=='') {
        alert('Debes llenar los campos de Peso y Dosis');
        exit;
    }

    if ($concentracion=='') {
    $resultado = ($peso * $dosis);
    $resultado = Math.round($resultado*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
    $('#resultado').html('Debes administar <span style="color: #009A8F; font-size: 30px;">' + $resultado + '</span> mg. de farmaco.<br />');
    } 

    else {
        $("#flipswitch").on("change", function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "off")

    $resultado = ($peso * $dosis);
    $resultado = Math.round($resultado*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
    $resultado2 = (($peso * $dosis) / ($concentracion * 10));
    $resultado2 = Math.round($resultado2*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);

    $('#resultado').html('Debes administar <span style="color: #009A8F; font-size: 30px;">' + $resultado + '</span> mg. de farmaco.<br /> Dedes administar <span style="color: #009A8F; font-size: 30px;">'+ $resultado2 + '</span> ml. del producto.');

            else {

    $resultado = ($peso * $dosis);
    $resultado = Math.round($resultado*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
    $resultado2 = (($peso * $dosis) / ($concentracion));
    $resultado2 = Math.round($resultado2*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);

    $('#resultado').html('Debes administar <span style="color: #009A8F; font-size: 30px;">' + $resultado + '</span> mg. de farmaco.<br /> Dedes administar <span style="color: #009A8F; font-size: 30px;">'+ $resultado2 + '</span> ml. del producto.');
    exit;
}};
});</script>
```

Something is wrong with the script?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. Also as a side note - it's a very bad habit - naming variables/methods/functions in your native language. Imagine if someone who's native language uses hieroglyphs or cyrillic alphabet did this, and you had to support that code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.

A few practical advice:

1. Use an integrated development environment (IDE) to write better code. See for instance this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794719/best-ide-for-html5-javascript-css-jquery-support-with-gui-building-tools) for suggestions. IDEs have built-in error-checking and let you know where and what you code misses.
2. You might also want to use an online validator, e.g. http://www.jslint.com/
3. As Eihwas indicates, correct code layout will help a lot when other people are to read your code. You can fix your code layout with tools like this, http://jsbeautifier.org/, great tools, but it's better to learn to code correctly. It is way easier to read and maintain well-written code.

If your code still does not work, please elaborate your question.